# Facebook iOS Deferred link `url` always return `nil`

Tags: ios, swift, facebook, notifications, deferred

anyone can help me??, I'm trying to use Deffered link of Facebook with the function:

```
 AppLinkUtility.fetchDeferredAppLink { (url, error) in ... }
```

It doesn't matter which way I put it the code, alway the `url` is `nil`

What are the steps necessary to reproduce this issue?
Very simple to describe:
1- Login to your Facebook
2- Then Click https://developers.facebook.com/tools/app-ads-helper.
2- Select an app you want to test from drop down.
3- Hit submit.
4- At the bottom you will find 'Deep Link Tester' under Developer Tools.
5- Hit 'Test Deep Link' and in the dialog you can enter your deep link.
6- Select both 'Send Notification' and 'Send Deferred' check marks.
7- Then you will get a notification to your facebook app.
8- Tap in the notification and it is opened the App Store.
9- Install the App through Xcode.

Then in my code I tried at least 5 variants:

For example I tried this:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

        // Set the trackings to true in test mode
        Settings.setAdvertiserTrackingEnabled(true)
        Settings.isAdvertiserIDCollectionEnabled = true
        Settings.isAutoLogAppEventsEnabled = true

        // Initialize the Facebook SDK
        ApplicationDelegate.initializeSDK(nil)

        AppLinkUtility.fetchDeferredAppLink { (url, error) in
            if let url = url {
                print(url)
            }
            print(error as Any)
        }
}
```

No matter which variant I try, the result is always the same, `url = nil`

I'm using:

- Xcode Version: `12.4`
- Swift Version: `5.2`
- Installation Facebook SDK with `SPM`

I did some search before, and nothing it's working for me:
(NOT WORKINKG).
[iOS - Test getting Facebook deferred deep link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63758456/ios-test-getting-facebook-deferred-deep-link).

(ALSO NOT WORKING)
[How to use Facebook deferred deep linking feature for new installs and to test the same before publishing iOS App to appStore?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30352690/how-to-use-facebook-deferred-deep-linking-feature-for-new-installs-and-to-test-t)

(NOT MY CASE)
[iOS - Test getting Facebook deferred deep link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63758456/ios-test-getting-facebook-deferred-deep-link)

(DIFFERENT SITUATION NOW THAT WE HAVE TO IMPLEMENT THE IDFA CONSENT OF THE USER)
[Facebook deferred deep link on iOS not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32655681/facebook-deferred-deep-link-on-ios-not-working)

(WITHOUT ANSWER)
https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/77046
https://developers.facebook.com/community/threads/304205737647076/?locale=es_LA

**SPECIAL NOTE:**
This code:     `ATTrackingManager.requestTrackingAuthorization(completionHandler:)` never shows the Prompt and always return `denied` in a real device(iPhone 12 and iPhone SE(2nd Generation) iOS 14.4 both). I don't know if that matters with this issue, but I think that it's important to mention that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently the issue it's with IDFA that always is 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000, hopefully when this problem is solved this issue disappear.
From the Facebook team:
"Thanks for your response. The returned appLinkData is always null since the ads id is invalid."

https://developers.facebook.com/support/bugs/349628616375797/

#### UPDATE:

The issue it's of Facebook, more details here:
https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/278254417309196